# Biztalk Adapter Pack install - not seeing WCF-SQL adapter

Tags: sql-server, installation, biztalk

I would like to use the WCF-SQL adapter to push data from BizTalk to SQL Server.  I have installed the WCF LOB Adapter SDK SP2 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23015) and the BizTalk Adapter Pack 2.0 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2755).  Based on the install instructions, I did a custom install of the LOB SDK and selected the BizTalk Server Addin to be installed.  I am using BizTalk 2010.

After installing both of those, and restarting, when I go into the BizTalk admin console, I don't see the WCF-SQL adapter listed under Platform Settings > Adapters.  If I try to add a new adapter, the Adapter dropdown is empty.

Why can't I see the WCF-SQL adapter after installing the adapter pack?  What do I need to do to successfully complete the install and starting using it?

**Update:**
I also tried the installers off of the Biztalk 2010 ISO.  Both of them said that they detected an older version and would replace it.  But still, after installation and a restart, same situation as above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that I was installing the 64bit version of the adapter pack but I am using 32bit BizTalk and so I had to install the 32bit adapter pack.  After that, the WCF-SQL adapter appeared in the list.